# How do I transform my maths totals into a time duration?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

At work we use a spreadsheet to calculate how long delivery will take to complete, depending on people working on delivery and the amount we receive.

It frustrates me that we end up with a value of say `3.75` hours.
The `.75` actually represents .75 of an hour and not 1hr 25minutes like you may first have thought.

I'm wanting the spreadsheet to say the time `3:45` minutes, not 3:75 minutes.

Is this even possible?

It gets more tricky though as we have to assume we will process 200 pieces per hour so the formula is slightly backwards. For example:

- Fill Grade: 55 (pieces in each crate)
- Crates: 10
- Total Pieces 550 (fill grade * crates)
- Process Time:  (total pieces /200)
- Clear rail time (puting stock out on shop floor, total pieces/400)
- Total time = ???

I'm wanting to do this because of the stupidity of our current system. We print the spreadsheet then use a calculator to add up all the values. We are effectively just using the grid of the Excel spreadsheet to rota in people's time.

***** Updated information *****

[Click here to see a screenshot of the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7dYD.jpg).

You can see that 'Pro Time' and 'C/R Time' is now correct but the total is wrong. I'm also having to total 'Pro Time' and 'C/R Time' by adding up in the boxes just to the right-hand side as you can see.

Advice?

Comment: Is you Total Time sum of Process Time and Clear rail time?

Comment: Have provided a solution under that assumption anyways. The idea is to divide whatever formula you have by 24 and then format the cell/column as time.

Comment: I think I must be calculating process time and clear rail time differently because The total is incorrect.

Comment: if you use divide by 24 on on Process Time and Clear Rail Time, then you should not use it on Total Time, as the conversion is already done. In such a case, Total time is just addition of the previous two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is whatever your formula in Total time is - let's assume it is (Process Time + Clear Rail time), then enter the formula there as `(Process Time + Clear Rail time)/24`.

**IMP: That divide by 24 should be included, which is an addition to whatever formula you had there before.**

Then select your `Total Time column>> Format Cells (also Ctrl+1)>>Select Time (HH:MM:SS type)`

This will show your value in hours, mins and seconds.

PS: (based on comments) IMP - if you use *divide by 24* on on Process Time and Clear Rail Time, then **you should not use it on Total** Time, as the conversion is already done. In such a case, Total time is just addition of the previous two.

Illustrative Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the fractional(modulus) part e.g. the .75. divide by 100 and then multiply by 60. (or just simply multiply by 0.6.

e.g. (where `C4` contains the hours and centi hours (if that's the correct term).

```
=MOD(C4,1) * 0.6
```

Assuming the above is in `D4` ..

Then in `E4` `=INT(C4)+D4`

However datetime might be a better route. Note sue of the functions but then you could add. In short datetime, if I recall correctly is a number eg something like Date+1 adds a day.

Comment: I thought this, but how can i isolate the section after the decimal?

Comment: That actually worked! But it's only saying the minutes and not the hours

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost there now (I fell asleep last night). I've updated my question to show a screenshot of my current problem.